# Error when building a project in Visual Studio CS106 Unexpected character ' File: .NETFramework,Version4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs

Tags: visual-studio

When building a project in Visual Studio 2015 I get the following error: CS106 Unexpected character ' File: .NETFramework,Version4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

David

Comment: Look in c:\users\yourname\appdata\local\temp for the file.  You can safely delete it.  But you certainly want to first find out why it got corrupted, disk damage is rarely an isolated event.

Comment: Hi, I deleted this file and restarted Visual Studio and I'm still getting this error. This error occurred after Windows 10 updated itself. For the moment though I'm targeting .NET Version 4.6 for my project which is working fine.